# Kotlin highlighting not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

It seems the Kotlin plugin in Eclipse does not start.

> An internal error occurred during: "Install semantic highlighting".
> Preference node "org.jetbrains.kotlin.core" has been removed.

When opening a Kotlin file (not doing any Kotlin, this is just a build.gradle.kts), all is red.

> Cannot access script base class
> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.core.script.template.ProjectScriptTemplate'. Check your module
> classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

It was working fine two days ago, I don't think I updated anything, and suddenly reopening my workspace it didn't work anymore.

Tried:

- reinstalling the plugin
- deleting all caches (in Workspace, in Eclipse folder, in home/.eclipse and .gradle
- new eclipse from scratch
- new workspace from scratch
- new Gradle project from scratch

Eclipse 2023-12. Last version of plugins. Gradle 8.5. Windows 11. Java Oracle 21.

I've looked for the error, found some mentions of transient bugs, but mostly in IntelliJ and not linked to the Eclipse plugin.

Is there a specific cache I might have missed ? A configuration I could change ? Where is this module classpath the error talks about ? (I'm not building any Java module in my project so I assume it's not related to my project's classpath)

Update: Now tried on another machine, in an eclipse that never had the plugin. Installed it, created new Gradle project (that automatically comes with initialized with .kts settings and build). Same issue.
So probably not cache related, but I now wonder why it worked for so long on my first case...

Comment: Make sure to use the [_Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse_ plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-kotlin-eclipse), not the [Kotlin plugin from JetBrains](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-eclipse) which is badly maintained. Be aware that Kotlin is not vendor-neutral.

Comment: I do (when it worked and when it stopped working). The Jetbrains one is a dependency of the enhanced one.

Comment: The _Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse_ plugin is a fork of the plugin from JetBrains, who have failed to maintain their stuff. Not the other way round. Please edit your question and add the information which of the two Kotlin plugins of which version you installed from where.